# undefined method `grid' for #<#<Class:0x007f89aefb1370>:0x007f89b035c078>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flexbox

ERROR: `undefined method`grid' for #<#:0x007f89b035c078>`

**home.haml**

```
.full-height.row.middle-xs.white-text.center-xs.main-background.no-margin{style: "background-color:red;"}
=grid xs:10,sm:8,md:6,lg:4 do
    .big-padding.blue.text-left.white-text
        %h1.no-margin.bold.light-blue-text Social Network
        %p.no-margin Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora autem facilis, culpa doloremque blanditiis. Pariatur nesciunt quas neque, tempora ipsam unde, ab quae, laboriosam eos consequatur enim numquam recusandae asperiores.
        .top-space
```

**Gemfile**

```
...
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
gem 'flexbox_rb'
gem 'haml-rails'
...
```

**application.scss**

```
 *= require flexboxgrid
 *= require colors
 *= require common
 *= require main
 *= require_self
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu archivo _application.css_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer la gema [no funciona con rails 5.x](https://github.com/urielhdz/flexbox_rb/issues/5), de hecho el último cambio subido es de hace 2 años atrás, así que lo más seguro es que el proyecto esté abandonado.
Lo mejor que podrías hacer es usar la librería flexbox [directamente](https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid) de su fuente en vez de usar wrappers desactualizados. Tus opciones, de la simple a la más compleja son:

- Acceder al css contenido en su cdn con:

  ```
  %link{:href => "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/
  ```
- [Descargar](https://github.com/kristoferjoseph/flexboxgrid/releases) la librería y agregarla a tu carpeta de assets.
- Usar [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) y agregarla a tu `package.json` con `npm i flexboxgrid --save`

Luego en vez de hacer:

```
=grid xs:10,sm:8,md:6,lg:4 do
```

deberías usar como equivalente algo como:

```
.col-xs-10.col-sm-8.col-md-6.col-lg-4
```